# Publish issue in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, deployment

I published my WPF project on IIS on server computer, and install the application on client over the network, every thing was fine, but now I have licence file for each computer, I used UUID to generate a licence file (dll file).

Now If I published with server licence when I install the application on client, the application will not work with server licence.

So, my question is can I install specific file on each computer instead of the other when I install the application over IIS?

Hope this clear.

Comment: Is this `ClickOnce` deployment?

Comment: @OmegaMan Yes, It is.